# Evaluate the Limit: $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{\ln x}$

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{\ln x}$

If $\frac {0^+}{\ln(0^+)}$

Wouldn't that equal $\frac{0}{0}$

Can some explain why the answer is $\frac{0}{-\infty}=0$

Comment: because log of zero is minus infinity.

Comment: @ Shailesh Log and ln of 0 is infinity? Can you point to a reference chart?

Comment: Use definition of log.  $e^? = 0$ ?  This question mark has to be replaced by $-\infty$

Comment: Because $\lim_{x \to -\infty} e^x = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what we can do here is say that the limit of a quotient is the quotients of the limits, provided the limits exist. That is
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x}{\ln(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to 0^+}x}{\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln(x)}$$
And what do we notice about the numerator? Well it is getting closer and closer to $0$, and what about the denominator? The denominator is approaching $-\infty$. And so what is consequently happening is that we are taking a really small number and dividing it by a really big number. Because of this, we can say that you can make the quotient as close to zero as you want, provided you make $x$ small enough, which in essence is what a limit is. So yes,
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x}{\ln(x)}=0$$
And if you wanted to get technical, it follows for that for any real number $\epsilon$, you could find a value $X$, such that whenever $x<X$, $\left|0-\frac{x}{\ln(x)}\right|<\epsilon$. In other words you can always find a small enough $x$ so that you can be within $\epsilon$ of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You know that: Log(0^+) = -infinity.

Comment: Technically $\log(0)$ is undefined, but $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \log(x)=-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that from some point, ${x\over \ln x}$ is negative and is never to change its sign again as $x$ tends zero from above. We therefore get ${-a\over \ln x}>{x\over \ln x}>{a\over \ln x}, a>0$ for a sufficiently small $x$. ($x<a$ for instance would work, if $a<1$). You can now use the Squeeze Theorem.